# Remove specific emoji from an already reacted message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want my bot to remove a specific emoji (among many) he reacts after fetching in a message. I use this line to remove all emoji from a specific user :

```
reaction.users.remove(user.id);
```

But the documentation :

```
.remove()
Removes all users from this reaction.
```

Is it possible to do ? I don't want to remove all reaction from my bot.

Comment: Are you able to target a character reference for the emoji or is it an image file?

Comment: Yes it's an embed message that my bot posted earlier

Comment: Without seeing an example of the message code you'd have to find a value that contains the text of the bot response message then try string.replace to remove the characters that refer to the emoji you want gone.

Comment: If you are answering your own question, create an _Answer_, do not put the answer _**in**_ the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchedMsg.reactions.resolve(emojiIDtoRemove).users.remove(user.id);
```